# Uber Eats API - Fail to collect reports (Could not parse json: readObjectStart: expect { or n, but..)

Tags: uber-api

We are facing an error when we are trying to request UberEats API to collect report about our restaurants based on the Ubereats documentation [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/api/v1/post-eats-report).

The error :

```bash
'{"error":"Could not parse json: readObjectStart: expect { or n, but found \x00, error found in #0 byte of ...||..., bigger context ...||..."}'
```

We tried to run the query in python and postman and still facing the same error.

Need help to understand where we failed.

Here the python code run in VSC

```py
import requests
import json

payload = {
    "report_type": "FINANCE_SUMMARY_REPORT",
    "store_uuids": "xxx",
    "start_date": "2022-09-01",
    "end_date": "2022-09-15"
}

headers = {
    "authorization": "Bearer xxx"
}

report_response = requests.post('https://api.uber.com/v1/eats/report', data=payload, headers=headers)

report_response.text
```

```
'{"error":"Could not parse json: readObjectStart: expect { or n, but found \x00, error found in #0 byte of ...||..., bigger context ...||..."}'
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the payload to valid JSON string and send the request.

```python
headers = {
  "Authorization" : "*********",
  "Content-Type" : "application/json"
}
```

```python
import json

response = requests.post("https://api.uber.co/v1/eats/report", data = json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```